# R: Adding duplicate rows where date changes by one day back to a set date

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, duplicates

I have a large dataframe (df) where "DateTime" defines the time of an event happening (Event = 1) for each animal (1-2), which has a number of other variables (e.g., Variable) associated with it. I want to get these data set up for a Cox Proportional Hazards analysis and need to lengthen the data set appropriately.

For each animal, I want to create a new duplicate row for each day back to one set date for all birds (9/27 in this example). All other variables will remain the same as the input except for "Event" which will be zero in the new rows only.

Have been learning tidyverse recently, but honestly not sure where to start.

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime = DateTime, Event = 1, Animal = 1:2, Variable = c(2.4, 1.5))
df

             DateTime Event Animal Variable
1 2019-10-01 20:21:12     1      1      2.4
2 2019-09-29 20:42:20     1      2      1.5
```

Desired Output:

```
DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-27 20:21:12",  "2019-09-28 20:21:12", "2019-09-29 20:21:12", "2019-09-30 20:21:12", "2019-10-01 20:21:12","2019-09-27 20:42:20", "2019-09-28 20:42:20", "2019-09-29 20:42:20" ), tz = "", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
df2 <- data.frame(DateTime = DateTime2, Event = (c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)), Animal = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), Variable = c(2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4, 1.5,1.5,1.5))
df2
             DateTime Event Animal Variable
1 2019-09-27 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
2 2019-09-28 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
3 2019-09-29 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
4 2019-09-30 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
5 2019-10-01 20:21:12     1      1      2.4
6 2019-09-27 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
7 2019-09-28 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
8 2019-09-29 20:42:20     1      2      1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

initDate <- as.Date('2019-09-27')

df %>%
  mutate(daysSince = as.integer(as.Date(DateTime) - initDate) + 1L) %>%
  uncount(daysSince) %>%
  group_by(across(-Event)) %>%
  mutate(DateTime = paste((as.Date(DateTime) - rev(1:n())) + 1L, format(DateTime, '%H:%M:%S')),
         Event = replace(Event, row_number() != n(), 0L)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   DateTime, Animal, Variable [8]
  DateTime            Event Animal Variable
  <chr>               <dbl>  <int>    <dbl>
1 2019-09-27 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
2 2019-09-28 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
3 2019-09-29 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
4 2019-09-30 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
5 2019-10-01 20:21:12     1      1      2.4
6 2019-09-27 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
7 2019-09-28 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
8 2019-09-29 20:42:20     1      2      1.5
```

Comment: Thanks - had to update packages, but that works too now.

Comment: Intelligent solution!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this in base R would be to create the sequence of dates for each date in your `DateTime` column. This sequence would act as the DateTime column for a new data frame (one new data frame per row of the original data frame). The other fields would be very straightforward to construct from there.

We can create these dataframes in a list and then `rbind` them all together to get our result. For example:

```r
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) {
  dt <- rev(seq(df$DateTime[i], as.POSIXct("2019-09-27"), by = "-1 day"))
  data.frame(DateTime = dt, Event = c(rep(0, length(dt) - 1), 1),
             Animal = df$Animal[i], Variable = df$Variable[i])}))

df2
#>              DateTime Event Animal Variable
#> 1 2019-09-27 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
#> 2 2019-09-28 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
#> 3 2019-09-29 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
#> 4 2019-09-30 20:21:12     0      1      2.4
#> 5 2019-10-01 20:21:12     1      1      2.4
#> 6 2019-09-27 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
#> 7 2019-09-28 20:42:20     0      2      1.5
#> 8 2019-09-29 20:42:20     1      2      1.5
```

Comment: Great. Thanks I'll work through this later today and make sure I understand it, but it definitely works.